# What causes tf-nightly to download every nights repo in github actions?

Tags: tensorflow, github

I have an action in a private repo that does `pip install -e`, where one of the setup.py requirements is `tf-nightly`. It seems that this causes all the past builds to be downloaded and then actions says `No space left on device`. What is the proper fix here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to have been that I had a numpy requirement of 1.18. I am not sure if it was downloading until it found a compatible version, or it just caused some other bug. Making the requirement simply `numpy` resolved the issue.

Comment: I can't understand what you did to fix the issue. Can you explain more?