# Tflite-model-maker is downloading several files endless

Tags: python, bash, tensorflow, ubuntu, installation

I'm trying to install TensorFlow using this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/modify/model_maker/image_classification). So, when I run the following command on my terminal:

$ pip install -q tflite-model-maker

This command starts to download several files, but this process never ends. I have an Ubuntu machine, and I don't know how to resolve this. This command already download more than 50 GB files, until fill my SSD completely.

[image]

I've tryied some solutions using these links, but I can't find the solution.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/51031

I've found a similar question, but without answer:
[What causes tf-nightly to download every nights repo in github actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65145690/what-causes-tf-nightly-to-download-every-nights-repo-in-github-actions)

Comment: Try installing the requirements first? (e.g. `pip install -r requirements.txt` https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution elsewhere (https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/tflite-model-maker-installation/16577/3).

Once you are connected to a runtime consider "use a fallback runtime version" you can access if by following the `tools > command palette` or `ctrl+shift+P`. Further instructions in the link above. Use it as a patch to the problem until a better solution is presented it.

Comment: apparently (according to a non-answer posted as an answer), `use a fallback runtime version` is no longer in the command palette.

Answer (score 0):

create a file name setup.py

paste the below code:

```
import subprocess
import sys
from git import Repo

print("Cloning repo...")


git_url = "https://github.com/Shubham654/Tensorflow-examples.git"
repo_dir = "tensorflow-model-maker"

try:
    Repo.clone_from(git_url, repo_dir)

except:
    pass

subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "-r", "./tensorflow-model-maker/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/requirements.txt"])
```

run `pip install GitPython` for git module and then
run `python setup.py` file and done.

now you can import

```
from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
from tflite_model_maker import image_classifier
from tflite_model_maker.config import ExportFormat
from tflite_model_maker.config import QuantizationConfig
from tflite_model_maker.image_classifier import DataLoader
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions to clone the source code from Github and then install, this worked for me:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/examples
cd examples/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/pip_package
pip install -e .
```

https://pypi.org/project/tflite-model-maker/